# Samba + Mac = Problems

Tags: raspbian, streaming-video, samba

I am running Raspbian and as of this afternoon have `update`'d and `upgrade`'d.

I am using my Raspberry Pi (2) as a Samba (`apt-get install samba`) 24/7 server/torrent box. Everything on the Pi itself is running smoothly.

When trying to stream media from the Pi, my Mac (mid 2014 Retina MacbookPro, SSD, 16 GB RAM) absolutely hates it. Finder ends up crashing beyond recovery. It won't "relaunch" or open at all after stopping a video stream to VLC. When trying to reboot my Mac gets stuck and I have to shut it down by force (different question altogether). The stream constantly stutters (after maybe 2 mins of trying to open at all); I am unable to stream even a 720p mkv file. I cannot tell where the bottleneck is coming from.

My USB HDD is ext4 and older but I'm confident that's not the issue. I'm currently connecting to the Pi with `smb://` protocol, but read that `cifs://` protocol might be faster. However, I get the same results, possibly even worse with `cifs`. Navigating the file system is a little laggy, but nothing out of the ordinary. Trying to copy a file to my Mac kills Finder again.

What complicates things is that on my iPad mini, I use the [FileExplorer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fileexplorer/id499470113?mt=8) app and things work perfectly fine. It takes no time to open and streaming very, very rarely stutters.

I don't have any Windows machines, so I can't compare it to that. I'm running OS X 10.11.3. I read a couple threads, namely [this one](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=13695) to see if there's anything I can do to boost performance.

Is there anything I can do to speed things up with Samba? Should I try a different protocol? Would just a normal FTP connection be better? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: If you don't use Windows why use Samba. It doesn't even work well on Windows. Try `afp` - install `netatalk` on the Pi.

Comment: I have the exact same setting as you, everything works fine for me. Did you mount your volume to local on mac?

Comment: @doodle yeah, it mounts to `/Volumes/`.

Comment: @Milliways I'll check it out, thanks for the advice

Comment: @Milliways wow, there's no comparison. If you want to write up an answer, I'll give it to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to communicate with Windows why use Samba.

Try `afp` - install `netatalk` on the Pi.

In addition to improved performance it is natively supported by Finder.

There are a couple of drawbacks.

By default it maps your Home directory, although others can be added.

I have never been able to get `afp` to share the Pi root directory. In this case I use `ssh` to transfer files on the Pi itself.